# How to introduce yourself?

Tags: word-choice, british-english

I am using British English. While addressing a gathering or talking to a new person, how do you introduce yourself? Is it "I am Phani" or "This is Phani"?

Comment: "I am" or "My name is".

Comment: Related: [I myself Naresh](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/143519/i-myself-naresh-as-an-introduction) | [I don't think we've been introduced](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/187000/do-both-of-these-introductions-mean-the-same-thing-and-make-sense)

Answer (score 3):

**If they can see you**, that is, you're meeting in person, you use one of these:

> I am [name].
>   Nice to meet you, I'm [name].
>   Hello, my name is [name].

**If they can't see you,** like if you're introducing yourself over the phone, you can use

> This is [name].

Answer (score -1):

Can't comment to tell Andrew that I accidentally flagged his comment so I'll write an answer instead and hope he sees it.

Phani; as pointed out by Dan, the correct way of introducing yourself is by saying, "Hello, my name is Phani."

If you are introducing someone else, that is when you would use, "This is (name).".